# Johnny five application exits unexpectedly when using methods

Tags: node.js, arduino

I am new in johnny five and also in arduino world. I have an UNO and I managed to connect it and install. I managed to wire a 3mm led with a 220 Ohm resistor. I can use several methods with it: `led.on`, `led.off`, etc. But when I use for example `led.blink` with small delay like 10ms the node application exits. With 100ms it blinks properly. It is also exit without any error when I use `led.pulse()`.

Do you guys have any idea what should be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've managed to get the led.pulse() working. First of all I've noticed that I using a very old nodeJS 0.12.7. I have updated it but got "serialport" build issues which has answered solutions but I did not want to install visual studio even if it's working. Then I downgraded johnny five library to 0.8.x and it is now working properly.